# T-SQL Trigger audit for update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I need to do a "trigger for update" for inserting the change of the table locations into the audit table.

I know how to access inserted / deleted for new and old value but i cant seem to find what i need to do for getting the different columns that been updated.(i know cursor use etc.)

Here the code i got for the moment (sry it's in french)

```
ALTER TRIGGER T_U_Locations ON Locations
FOR UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN

--Definition des valeurs
DECLARE @tempDuChangement VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE @nomDuChampChange VARCHAR(64);
DECLARE @idLocation INT;
DECLARE @ancienneV VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @nouvelleV VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @raison VARCHAR(50);


--Aquisition des valeurs sur les changement apportés
SET @tempDuChangement = CONVERT( VARCHAR(30) , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );

SET @nomDuChampChange = --HERE GOES THE CURRENT UPDATED COLUMN
SET @idLocation = (SELECT inserted.id FROM inserted);

SET @ancienneV = (SELECT /*HERE GOES THE CURRENT UPDATED COLUMN*/ FROM deleted);
SET @nouvelleV = (SELECT /*HERE GOES THE CURRENT UPDATED COLUMN*/ FROM inserted);

-- Crée une nouvelle entré dans la table Audits avec les information relative
INSERT INTO Audits
VALUES
(
    @tempDuChangement,
    @nomDuChampChange,
    @ancienneV,
    @nouvelleV,
    @idLocation,
    'raison test'
)
END
```

Comment: refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that it will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `id` is unique (and not changed in the update), I htink you want:

```
insert into Audits (time, columnName, oldValue, newValue . . . )  -- always include the column list
    select Current_Timestamp, v.colname, v.oldValue, v.newValue, . . .
    from inserted i join
         deleted d
         on i.id = d.id outer apply
         (values ('col1', d.col1, o.col1),
                 ('col2', d.col2, o.col2),
                 ('col3', d.col3, o.col3),
                 . . .
         ) v(colname, oldValue, newValue)
     where v.oldValue <> v.newValue or
           v.oldValue is null and v.newValue is not null or
           v.oldValue is not null and v.newValue is null;
```

Basically, you are unpivoting the data by column, using `outer apply`, so you need to include all the columns.  The `where` clause then gets the ones that have been modified.